# How to prevent GreenDAO from generating my models for me? I only need their DAO counterparts

Tags: java, android, greendao

I am following this tutorial:
http://www.devteam83.com/en/tutorial-greendao-from-scratch-part-1/

and I am really dissatisfied with `GreenDAO` because it intervenes with my app logic. First of all I package by feature, not by layer, and I don't just pile up my classes in groups like **models, views, controllers** etc. But it just dumps them in a folder. Second of all, I already have my models and I dont want another copy of each model of mine, I just need the DAO counterpart.

**DaoGenerator** only has one method - **generateAll**. I expected something like **generateDAOsOnly** but there is no such thing.

Is there a way around this? Some kind of general setting or something?

I want the **DB** implementation to be at the periphery of my system and not intertwined with it. I want my business models to remain pure and not entangled in `GreenDAO`'s logic.

Comment: so you should take a look at [storio](https://github.com/pushtorefresh/storio) maybe?

Comment: so this is how it works and there is no workaround?

Comment: you are welcome to change the way the generator works: https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/tree/master/DaoGenerator/src/de/greenrobot/daogenerator